# How to ignore pmd LocalVariableCouldBeFinal when using Hibernate accessors

Tags: java, pmd

In the codebase I'm working in, we use Hibernate so a lot of our objects have a public getter, but a private setter.  As such, pmd thinks these member vars could be declared final (via LocalVariableCouldBeFinal).  Any thoughts/suggestions on how to address this rather than on a per field basis?  We do usually annotate our setters with the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unused"})  // used by hibernate
```

Comment: [LocalVariableCouldBeFinal](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3/rules/optimizations.html#LocalVariableCouldBeFinal) is a rule that refers to *local* variables that are only assigned once. It has nothing to do with member variables (fields).

Comment: Maybe you can post the code that triggers the warning and mark the line where the warning appears?

Comment: oh... I may be confused... it's probably the variable being passed into the setter that it's complaining about

Comment: actually, I take that back... that looks like MethodArgumentCouldBeFinal